# "typical of" vs. "typical for"

Tags: prepositions

> The high efficacy of the new drug is coupled with a lack of adverse effects that are typical **for** high-dose parenteral interferon administration.

Is it okay, or is it better to use **of**?

> The high efficacy of the new drug is coupled with a lack of adverse effects that are typical **of** high-dose parenteral interferon administration.

I google for "effects typical of\for" and seem to find both variations:

> Similarly, toxic side effects typical **for** systemic amphotericin B application as fever, chills, or nausea were not noted.
>
> Sleep effects typical **of** SSRIs were greater with PAR 20 mg/day than CIT 20 mg/day, suggesting greater effects on 5HT uptake blockade

Is "for" better because it's "administration", not just "interferon"?

Comment: You could even use **with** there. http://tinyurl.com/z2fs8a2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quite subtle area; I doubt that many native English speakers would be able to articulate the rules here. My initial thought was that there might be a distinction between describing a set of effects that have been seen in the past

> typical of (some summary of past experience)

in contrast with considering a hypothetical or anticipated future situation

> typical for (situation where we might expect, but have yet to see)

I then saw [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139622/typical-of-or-typical-for) over on the English Language site. I don't see a definitive answer there, but a suggestion of another distinction (extrinsic v intrinsic), which I cannot pretend to understand. We can note that "of" appears to be far more widely used  than "for", but popularity is no guarantee of correctness.

I am pretty confident that most native speakers would say:

> this weather is typical for July

and

> that behaviour is typical of him

and I still fail to articulate a rule to explain why.

Comment: re: extrinsic v intrinsic: "for" seems to be used when the object (e.g. "July") has no choice in the matter (extrinsic), whereas "of" is used when the object (e.g. "him") does have a choice (intrinsic). So "bad luck is typical for him", and "bad behavior is typical of him". I think there can be exceptions to this, but this seems the general rule.

Answer (score 0):

*X is typical for Y* means that behavior X was observed and it is expected behavior of something that is Y.  If we did not observe the behavior X then it would be better to say *X would be typical for Y*.

*X is typical of Y* simply expresses that Y is expected behavior of X.  It can imply that we observed X but this is not necessarily true.